# How to use gps in android with locationManager?

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

I watched many discussion about it but I still didn't suceed to display gps coordinates in an android app with location manager:

If I understood well i have to do first :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

to charge location manager, and after

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
```

to update location
and finally

```
Location position = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

The porblem is that this is not working. So I suppose I did not understand well. Please tell me what are the good syntax.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Edit:

I added these permissions in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

Comment: Have you added permission in manifest or run time permission incase of API>=23?

Comment: I edited my message with the permissions I added. What do you mean by this "run time permission incase of API>=23" ?

Comment: If you are using android device marshmallow and nougat. Then you have to provide run time permission.

Comment: Ok thanks, how I add these permissions? Is there something like <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RUNTIME" /> ?

Comment: No, this is not run time permission. like this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: I would recommend Fused Location API as it is more reliable

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer but I cannot compile your code... Can you put a version that compile please ? Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Error:(32, 24) error: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(String,int,int,Gpslocation)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,LocationListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Gpslocation cannot be converted to LocationListener)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,PendingIntent) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Gpslocation cannot be converted to PendingIntent)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long,float,Criteria,PendingIntent) is not applicab
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to long)

Comment: no comments, no explanation, bad formatting. Code only answer = bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for getting location.

```
LocationManager locationManager;

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;// and ask for run time permission
}
Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (currentLocation != null) {
    mypoint = new GeoPoint(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
}
markerForCurrentLocation.setPosition(mypoint);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //Here you will get the current location of your GPS device
    mypoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    markerForCurrentLocation.setPosition(mypoint);
    mapController.animateTo(mypoint);
}
```

Method asking for runtime location permission

```
private void requestLocationPermission() {

    //method asking for runtime location permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```